# How to give shadow to a custom painted circle in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, paint

I am trying to make a circle appear more material. So I want to give it a shadow of some sort how do I do it with the Paint class in flutter

```
thumbPaint = Paint()
..color = Colors.white,
..style = PaintingStyle.fill;
```

Comment: if you want some shadow then use `Canvas#drawShadow()` method

Comment: like this  ```canvas.drawCircle().drawShadow();``` ?  How do I get the Path ??

Comment: like this `canvas.drawShadow(...)`

Comment: `"How do I get the Path ??"` - see [Path](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Path-class.html) official documentation

Answer (score 9):

You can use a [MaskFilter](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/MaskFilter-class.html) to create shadow effect. Just draw a circleB with slightly bigger radius using MaskFilter Paint before drawing your real circleA, you can get a circleA with shadow effect.

Check out this [circle](https://www.dropbox.com/s/sb0izeieko51zfz/Screen%20Shot%202020-01-02%20at%2012.54.31%20PM.png?dl=0) drew with below codes.

```
class Painter extends CustomPainter {

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    double radius = 100.0;
    canvas.translate(size.width/2, size.height/2); 
    Offset center = Offset(0.0, 0.0);
    // draw shadow first
    Path oval = Path()
        ..addOval(Rect.fromCircle(center: center, radius: radius+10));
    Paint shadowPaint = Paint() 
        ..color = Colors.black.withOpacity(0.3)
        ..maskFilter = MaskFilter.blur(BlurStyle.normal, 50);
    canvas.drawPath(oval, shadowPaint);
    // draw circle
    Paint thumbPaint = Paint()
        ..color = Colors.white
        ..style = PaintingStyle.fill;
    canvas.drawCircle(center, radius, thumbPaint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(Painter oldDelegate) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You could also use the [drawShadow](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Canvas/drawShadow.html) method.

```
@override
void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
  var path = Path();
  var myPaint = Paint();
  var center = Offset(size.width / 2, size.height / 2);

  myPaint.color = Color(0xff007AFF);

  path.addOval(Rect.fromCircle(center: center, radius: 50.0));

  canvas.drawShadow(path, Color(0xff000000), 3, true);
  canvas.drawPath(path, myPaint);
}
```

Result:

[image: circle with shadow]

Answer (score -2):

***Wrap it in a Boxdecoration.It has BoxShadow property***.

You can follow [this link](https://medium.com/jlouage/flutter-boxdecoration-cheat-sheet-72cedaa1ba20).

```
   new Container(
    decoration: new BoxDecoration(
      color: Colors.white,
      border: new Border.all(
          color: Colors.green,
          width: 5.0,
          style: BorderStyle.solid
      ),
      borderRadius: new BorderRadius.only(
        topLeft: new Radius.elliptical(40.0, 10.0),
        bottomLeft: new Radius.circular(20.0),
      ),
      boxShadow: [
        new BoxShadow(
          color: Colors.red,
          offset: new Offset(20.0, 10.0),
        )
      ],
      image: new DecorationImage(
          image: new AssetImage('assets/images/JL-Logo-150.png'),
      )
```

Comment: I am asking for custom Paint

Comment: https://gist.github.com/xalexchen/6589103

this link works with custom paint shadow.and is well functioned .hope it helps.

Comment: @A.S.M.Nesar Uddin Isn't that Java? How can that be used with Flutter...